# How to autoload inherited doctrine entity in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, entity, zend-framework3

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
class Person
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Employee extends Person
{
    // ...
}
```

How to define Autoload for above doctrine entity inheritance ? Or can we put each entity in separate file such as Entity\Person.php , Employee\Person.php ?

Comment: You should definitely split them in two different files as exposed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put every PHP class in its own file, if you want your project to be compatible with (for example) [PSR-4 (Autoloader)](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Citing from the PSR-4 specification:

> 3. When loading a file that corresponds to a fully qualified class name …
>
>    1. A contiguous series of one or more leading namespace and sub-namespace names, not including the leading namespace separator, in the fully qualified class name (a “namespace prefix”) corresponds to at least one “base directory”.
>    2. The contiguous sub-namespace names after the “namespace prefix” correspond to a subdirectory within a “base directory”, in which the namespace separators represent directory separators. The subdirectory name MUST match the case of the sub-namespace names.
>    3. The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in `.php`. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

So, if you create a class `Person` in `MyProject\Model` namespace, the autoloader will find it only in a `…/Model/Person.php` file. And an `Employee` class must go to a separate `…/Model/Employee.php` file in order to be available to the autoloader.